# How to add a custom attribute to a model in a controller on load?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this:

```
public function index()
{

    $allusers = User::get(['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'postcode', 'preferred_role_id', 'email']);

    return view('users.index', ['allusers' => $allusers]);

}
```

Now, `preferred_role_id` is an integer which points to an `id` in JobRoles model (job_roles) table, in where there is a field with a name of a job role. How do I pass that name to each of the users in `$allusers`? I would like to access it in the view like this:

```
@foreach ($allusers as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{$user->first_name}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{$user->job_role}}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 3):

You create a `BelongsTo` relationship from `User` to `JobRole`:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

In you `User` model, you can add the relationship like this:

```
public function jobRole() {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\JobRole::class, 'preferred_role_id');
}
```

Then change your view:

```
{{ $user->jobRole->name }}
```

To improve performance, you should use eager loading:

```
User::with('jobRole')->get(...);
```